# How can I account for a (missing) trailing slash when redirecting root directory to a subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

On my shared Apache hosting, I'm attempting to seamlessly redirect (without rewriting the URL in the client's browser) all requests to my website to a subdirectory named `/blog`. I'm doing this with a `.htaccess` file.

This is what I have so far (from [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216109967-Transparently-redirect-your-root-directory-to-a-subdirectory)):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

This works fine for URLs with a trailing slash.

For example when the user accesses `https://example.com/about/`, the files from `http://example.com/blog/about/` are served, and the URL remains `https://example.com/about/`.

**Problem**

When the user accesses `https://example.com/about` (no trailing slash), the files from `https://example.com/blog/about/` are served, but the URL in the browser changes to `https://example.com/blog/about/`. The URL change is not desired.

**Question**

How can I alter my `.htaccess` file to ensure that the URL in the client's browser does not change when the trailing slash is missing?

**Additional Info**

The only option I have checked in my provider's back-end is "force SSL". There are no other `.htaccess` files present on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing slash is being added by Apache's `mod_dir` module as `/blog/about/` is a real directory and trailing slash is added in front of directories to prevent directory listing.

You may use these rules:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash if desrtination is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^blog/ blog%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but using your code the problem remains (tested using new browser). When I enter `https://example.com/about` it still rewrites the URL to `https://example.com/blog/about/`.

Comment: These rules are working on my Apache so I suspect some other conflicting rule on your end. Can you show your complete .htaccess in your question and also tell where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: I too fear that there is some shared hosting magic happening. What I posted is the complete .htaccess file. It is located in the root folder of my webspace.

Comment: Now when I hit `https://example.com/about` it 404s. `https://example.com/about/` (with slash) works.

Comment: ok create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value and then check parent directory of this `.htaccess`

Comment: Thank you for your continued suggestions, but I'm going to cut my losses and call it a day (I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days). I'll accept the answer as it works on your box - I'm pretty sure there's some shared hosting weirdness going on my end.

Comment: Feel free to ask question anytime related to this issue in future as well, good luck.